# Adding Facebook Pixel event to Squarespace button click

Tags: javascript, facebook, pixel, squarespace

I'm trying to add a Facebook pixel event -- "ViewContent" -- to my Squarespace site. I have one page with one button, and I want to fire the event on the button click. It *feels* like it should be simple, but I'm consistently getting an error in Facebook Pixel Helper with my current setup.

I'm referencing this post: [Add FB pixel event code into button - Squarespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280109/add-fb-pixel-event-code-into-button-squarespace)

And as recommended in the answer, I'm using a per-page code injection in the header on this page: https://www.wearpapercrane.com/survey

This is what I have --

```
    <script>
    (function() {
        var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("sqs-block-button-element");
        var i, I;

        for (i=0, I=btns.length; i<I; i++) {
            btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                fbq("track", "ViewContent");
            });
        }
    })();
</script>
```

But here's what I get on the other end when I use Facebook Pixel Helper to validate --

[image]

(This is after the click, by the way ... the button opens the link in a separate tab, so this is going back to the page after the click and looking at Pixel Helper).

Is there something I'm missing that is resulting in this error?

I have the pixel installed and I have a "lead" event working properly on another page (using Squarespace's Form Embed feature), so I'm pretty sure it's a problem with this specific code injection.

Would love any and all recommendations. Thank you!!

Comment: Have you first of all verified that this click handler actually fires?

Answer (score 2):

The event is not firing because the answer you referenced (which I wrote) did not account for the fact that, when injecting the code via header injection (site-level or page-level), one must wait for the DOM to be loaded before attaching events to the elements.

The answer you have referenced has been updated, notably the following section:

```
<script>
    window.Squarespace.onInitialize(Y, function() {
        var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("sqs-block-button-element");
        var i;
        for (i=btns.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                fbq("track", "AddToCart");
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```